# local entry as filter criteria in wso2 esb mediation

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a sequence as part of proxy service which filters based on "Source and Regular Expression". I have defined source as element value coming as part of SOAP request and regular expression as "local entry defined in ESB". However, result is not what I am expecting.

Local Entry is defined as Inline Text (myFields) - FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3

Mediation sequence is defined as -
`<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="007">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="fieldName" expression="$body/fieldName/text()" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('fieldName')" regex="get-property('myFields')">
      <then>
         <log level="full" separator="*****YES*********">
            <property name="myFields" expression="get-property('myFields')"/>
         </log>
      </then>
      <else>
         <log level="full" separator="*********NO**************">
            <property name="myFields" expression="get-property('myFields')"/>
         </log>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>`

When I am sending SOAP request as - 
`<body>
<fieldName>FIELD1</fieldName>
</body>`

execution is always going to else part. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With filter mediator, regex attribute must be a string, not an expression.

You can use XPATH2 "matches"

Sample :

```
<inSequence>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="fieldName" expression="$body/fieldName/text()"/>
    <property xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" name="match" expression="fn:matches(syn:get-property('fieldName'),syn:get-property('myFields'))"/>
    <filter source="get-property('match')" regex="true">
        <then>
            <log level="full" separator="*****YES*********">
                <property name="myFields" expression="get-property('myFields')"/>
            </log>
        </then>
        <else>
            <log level="full" separator="*********NO**************">
                <property name="myFields" expression="get-property('myFields')"/>
            </log>
        </else>
    </filter>
    <log level="full"/>
</inSequence>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have enabled XPATH2 in ESB, but while adding this sequence logic, seeing following error message on management console : Sequence configuration is invalid :String index out of range: -1

Comment: This is the "inSequence" inside a proxy service definition : <proxy><description/><target><inSequence>...</inSequence></target></proxy>. I work with ESB 4.8.1

Comment: Is it not possible to have it outside proxy definition ? As part of sequence definition ?

Comment: Sure, you can define a named sequence and it's content will be what you find in my sample between <inSequence> and </inSequence> tags

Comment: I tried that Jean and that's where I got error as "Sequence configuration is invalid :String index out of range: -1"

Comment: <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestSOFSeq">
   <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
   <property name="fieldName" expression="$body/fieldName/text()"/>
   <property name="match" expression="fn:matches(syn:get-property('fieldName'),syn:get-property('testSOFLE'))"/>
   <filter source="get-property('match')" regex="true">
      <then>
         <log level="full" separator="**YES**"/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <log level="full" separator="**NO**"/>
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>

Comment: <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TestSOF2"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <sequence key="TestSOFSeq"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>

Comment: Thanks Jean, I have ESB version 4.6.0, I got it working by removing fn: as part of property "match" expression. However, I observed if I send fieldname as FIELD1 or FIELD111, still it is considered as match. Is there any way I can match with what has been entered as part of local entry only i.e. Local Entry is defined as Inline Text (myFields) - FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3